# Get return value inside a function with javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, meteor, xml-parsing

How can I get the 'return' value from alexa function?

I tried making a new function init() to wrap all the operation, but no luck. Not even error or something, and when I use

```
console.log(result.rank);
```

I receive the correct value in the console, without problems.

```
3
```

Code

```
rank: function() {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = this.url;
    var alexa = require('alexarank');
    function init(){
    alexa(a.hostname, function(error, result) {
        if (!error) {
          return result.rank;
        } else {
            console.log(error);
        }
      });
    }
    return init();
```

Comment: so you need to know [how to return a value from an asynchronous function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: Yes, i'm trying to get 'return' value

Comment: you can't synchronously return a value gained asynchronously - would need to know how you are calling the function in the question to offer real help (you may want to look into `callback functions` or `promises` though)

Comment: Is this in a Meteor method?

Comment: yes, is a meteor method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it,
passing a callback:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6847754/7693078

```
rank: function() {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = this.url;
    var alexa = require('alexarank');
    function ranking(x,y){ 
      alexa(a.hostname, function(error, result) {
        if (!error) {
           y(result.rank);
        } else {
           console.log(error);
        }
      });
    }
    ranking("x", function(y){
      var span = document.getElementById("ranking");
      var txt = document.createTextNode(y);
      span.appendChild(txt);
    });
  }
```

Comment: If this is a meteor method, it will run on the server where there is no document to create elements with...

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing to do in a Meteor method is to use `Meteor.wrapAsync`:

```
rank: function() {
    var alexa = require('alexarank');
    var alexaSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(alexa);
    var result = alexaSync(a.hostname);
    return result.rank;
}
```

`Meteor.wrapAsync` takes an asynchronous function which accepts a callback as it's last argument and makes it work as though it was synchronous (through the magic of Fibers)

---

Note that Meteor methods can also return promises and will wait for the promise to resolve. So if the library you are using supports promises you can make your function an async function and `await` the result from the library. Or wrap it's callback in your own promise and `await`/`return` that.

Comment: rank is undefined :c